# React-native: change text of a button

Tags: react-native

I've got a button "follow" and I would like to change the text when the user clicked on and when the follow is done. Here is my code:

```
 this.state = {
  user: [],
  textValue:'Followwww',
  result: [],
  dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
  })
};

 follow = (item) => {
// logout, once that is complete, return the user to the login screen.
fire.database().ref('follow').push({
  storeName: item.storeName,
  id_user: this.state.user.uid,
  id_store: item._key,
  follow: '1'
}).then(function(ref) {
    this.setState({ textValue: "Followed" })
    //alert('Vous êtes désormais abonné à : ' + item.storeName + '         !');
}).catch(function(error) {
    alert(error);
});
}

 <RkButton 
   rkType='rounded'
   onPress={() => this.follow(item)}
   style={styles.primary_button_list}
   contentStyle={styles.primary_button_text_list}>
   {this.state.textValue}
 </RkButton>
```

And I get this error :

> TypeError: this.state is not a function. (In 'this.state({textValue: "Followed"})', 'this.setState' is undefined)

I'm very new in React and I'd love to understand my mistake.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call:

```
//correct
this.setState({ textValue: "Followed" }}
```

instead of:

```
//wrong
this.state({ textValue: "Followed" })
```

Comment: Sh** sorry I've put the wrong code the code you added is the code I use. I update my question with the good code